# Pagina en blanco PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente `script`

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET["id"])) {
    print "<script>alert(\"No se pudo identificar el proveedor. Consulte la base de datos.\");window.location='../proveedores.php';</script>";
    exit();
} else{
    include "conexion.php";
    $sql = "UPDATE proveedores SET cuit_tipo = \"$_POST[cuit_tipo]\", cuit_dni = \"$_POST[cuit_dni]\",  cuit_al = \"$_POST[cuit_al]\", iva = \"$_POST[iva]\", direccion =\"$_POST[direccion]\", num = \"$_POST[num]\", piso = \"$_POST[piso]\", puerta = \"$_POST[puerta]\", ciudad = \"$_POST[ciudad]\", provincia = \"$_POST[provincia]\", cp = \"$_POST[cp]\", pais = \"$_POST[pais]\", codigo_area = \"$_POST[codigo_area]\", telefono = \"$_POST[telefono]\", web = \"$_POST[web]\" email = \"$_POST[email]\", created_at = NOW() WHERE id = \"$_GET[id]\"";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    if($query!=null){
        print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

En un principio, la idea es que se identifique el **ID** correspondiente al proveedor, si existe algún error identificándolo, salta el `alert`.

De estar todo bien, lo que debería hacer es actualizar datos de las filas relacionadas al **ID** seleccionado previamente.

Al incorporar o no los cambios, y darle click en el botón correspondiente, solo salta la página en blanco.

No logro dar con la manera correcta de formular es `script` para que actualice los datos editados.

He intentado darle `print` y `echo` a todas las variables, pero sigue saltando la página en blanco.

Comment: Para este tipo de casos es útil utilizar **AJAX**, ya que estás enlazando Javascript con PHP. Busca algunos ejemplos por si no lo sabes usar

Comment: Estas combinando `$_GET`y `$_POST`, debería ser uno u otro. Las cadenas en MySQL se expresan con comillas sencillas `'`.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por comentar! Cuando uso GET en la sentencia SQL, me sale undefined index por cada columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola he estado leyendo tu código

Estas utilizando los metodos `$_GET` y `$_POST` al mismo tiempo.

Vale me imagino que lo que quieres es actualizar los datos del proveedor
lo que se suele utilizar es un formulario  con uno de los dos métodos

por ejemplo

```html
<form action="Modificar_proveedores.php" method="GET">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

donde en la etiqueta `<form>` le agregas el atributo `Action` la cual apunta a tu documento `php` en este caso yo le he llamado `Modificar_proveedores.php`  y tambien le agrego el atributo `method` en este caso `GET`

Si utilizas `GET` en el metodo, en tu script debes utilizar `GET`  y Viceversa

Si el id del proveedor  no lo quieres mostrar en el formulario utiliza un  `<input>` con el atributo `hidden`

```html
<input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="xm234jq">
```

Luego en tu `script` cambia algunas cosas

```html
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET["id"])) {
    print "<script>alert(\"No se pudo identificar el proveedor. Consulte la base de datos.\");window.location='../proveedores.php';</script>";
    exit();
} else{
    require_once ("conexion.php");
    //Lo ideal es que primero asignes los valores del GET a unasvariables
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $cuit_tipo = $_GET['cuit_tipo'];
    $cuit_al = $_GET['cuit_al'];
    $cuit_dni = $_GET['cuit_dni'];
    $iva  = $_GET['iva'];
    $direccion = $_GET['direccion'];
    $num = $_GET['num'];
    $piso = $_GET['piso'];
    $puerta = $_GET['puerta'];
    $ciudad = $_GET['ciudad'];
    $provincia = $_GET['provincia'];
    $cp = $_GET['cp'];
    $pais = $_GET['pais'];
    $codigo_area = $_GET['codigo_area'];
    $telefono = $_GET['telefono'];
    $web = $_GET['web'];
    $created_at = date('d-m-Y'); //Hoy en el formato dia-mes-año
    
    $sql = "UPDATE proveedores SET cuit_tipo = '$cuit_tipo',
     cuit_dni = '$cuit_dni',
     cuit_al = '$cuit_al',
     iva =  '$iva',
     direccion = '$direccion',
     num = ' $num',
     piso = '$piso',
     puerta = '$puerta',
     ciudad = '$ciudad',
     provincia = '$provincia',
     cp = '$cp',
     pais = '$pais',
     codigo_area =' $codigo_area',
     telefono = '$telefono',
     web = '$web;
     created_at = '$created_at',
     WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    if($query!=null){
        print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

y la explicacion de por que te sale en blanco la pagina:

1. php no encuentra el parametro`Id` en la varaible `GET` y has puesto que finalice la ejecución  con el la función  `exit();`
   2.cuando utilizas el método `GET` y `POST` en formulario lo que estas haciendo es redirigir a esa pagina en la cual no tienes HTML  por eso sale en blanco

si lo que quieres es que no salga en blanco puedes hacer una de estas 3 opciones
1. Utilizar Ajax
2. incluir el script en la pagina actual
3. redirigir después de modificar

un saludo

Comment: Bueno, por fin. El script funciona. De entrada, me faltaban los `id` y `name` en algún de la página de edición previa a guardar con este `script`, razón por la cual, saltaba el `alert` informando el problema de  identificación, en este caso del `id` con la función `isset`, por lo que agregué los `input` en `hidden`.
Luego, lo demás era un simple problema de comas y sintaxis del `script`. Por ejemplo: al asignar el valor a `created_at` dentro del la variable `$sql` que estaría corriendo el `UPDATE`, sobra una coma. Luego de esas correcciones, el `script` funciona a la perfección. Mil gracias!